# Why the below code is giving different output when variable type is different?

Tags: c, char, int, bit

```
//o/p when i/p is 16 and 2 is 4 and if  variable is int then o/p will be 20;   

#define SETBIT(A,B) A|1<<B

int main(){
    char n,pos;
    printf("Enter a value");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter position");
    scanf("%d",&pos);
    printf("Value after setting %d",SETBIT(n,pos));
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d",&n);` the format specifier does not match the data type, and the other `scanf` too.

Comment: `scanf("%d",&n)` with `char n` yields undefined behavior. Same for `scanf("%d",&pos)`. In practice, `scanf` writes 4 bytes of data into a variable whose size is 1 byte (though these sizes in general are not dictated by the language standard, this is the case on most platforms). You need to make up your mind what type of data you want to scan from the keyboard. With `"%d"` - use `int`. For `char` - use `"%c"`.

Comment: Please submit formatted code

Comment: Aside: always use parentheses in a macro, like `#define SETBIT(A,B) (A|1<<B)`

Comment: @WeatherVane: I think you mean `((A)|1<<(B))`

Comment: No I meant what I wrote. If `A` or `B` arguments are macros, then they too will be parenthesised, but your version is safer.

Comment: @WeatherVane all macro arguments should be parenthesized in the macro. `SETBIT(1, 2|4)` may have a different result than `SETBIT(1, 6)`

Comment: `char n; scanf("%d",&n);` raises a warning on good compilers and those with warnings well enabled.  Save time.  Enable all warnings.

Answer (score 0):

For the `*scanf` functions, the `d` conversion specifier expects its corresponding parameter to have type `int *`; if that's not the case, then the behavior is *undefined*, and pretty much *any* result is possible.

If you want to use `char` for `pos` and `n`, then you must use `%hhd` instead of `%d` in the `scanf` call.

Comment: Still  output is same.